# Facebook Authentication fails using passport

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to create a login page with facebook authentication, it works just fine but next time onwards I get this message, the message seems like error is from their side but even after months it doesn't work. What could possibly be wrong here?
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68jxP.png) is the screenshot of the error.

```
    require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
        const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
        const ejs = require("ejs");
        const mongoose = require("mongoose");
        const session = require('express-session');
        const _ = require("lodash");
        const passport = require("passport");
        const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
        const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
        const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
        const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');
        
        
        const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing.";
        const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
        const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";
        const app = express();
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
        app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
        
        var profileName;
        
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
          extended: true
        }));
        
        app.use(session({
          secret: "Our little secret.",
          resave: false,
          saveUninitialized: false
        }));
        
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());
        
        mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://paritosh_dalai:Jinu1606@cluster0.mjxiq.mongodb.net/blogDB", {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
          useCreateIndex: true
        });
        
        const postSchema = {
          title: String,
          content: String,
          name: String
        };
        
        const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
          name: String,
          email: String,
          password: String,
          googleId: String,
          facebookId: String
        });
        userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
        userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);
        
        const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
        const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
        
        passport.use(User.createStrategy());
        
        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
          done(null, user.id);
        });
        
        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
          User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
          });
        });
        
        passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
            clientID: "process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
            clientSecret: "process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/blog",
            userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
          },
          function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
            profileName=profile.displayName;
            User.findOrCreate({
              googleId: profile.id,
              name: profile.displayName
            }, function(err, user) {
              return cb(err, user);
            });
          }
        ));
        
        passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
            clientID: "process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID",
            clientSecret: "process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/blog"
          },
          function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
            profileName = profile.displayName;
            User.findOrCreate({
              facebookId: profile.id,
              name: profile.displayName
            }, function(err, user) {
              return cb(err, user);
            });
          }
        ));
        
        
        app.get("/auth/google",
          passport.authenticate('google', {
            scope: ["profile"]
          })
        );
        
        app.get("/auth/google/blog",
          passport.authenticate('google', {
            failureRedirect: "/"
          }),
          function(req, res) {
            res.redirect("/blog");
          });
        
        app.get('/auth/facebook',
          passport.authenticate('facebook',{
            scope:["profile"]
          })
        );
        
        app.get('/auth/facebook/blog',
          passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            failureRedirect: '/'
          }),
          function(req, res) {
            // Successful authentication, redirect home.
            res.redirect('/blog');
          });
        
        app.get("/", function(req, res) {
          res.render("home");
        });
        
        
        app.get("/blog", function(req, res) {
          Post.find({}, function(err, posts) {
            res.render("blog", {
              startingContent: homeStartingContent,
              posts: posts
            });
          });
        
        });
        
        app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
          req.logout();
          req.session.destroy();
          res.redirect('/');
        });
        
        
        app.get("/compose", function(req, res) {
          if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.render("compose");
          } else {
            res.redirect("/");
          }
        });
        
        // app.get("/profile", function(req,res){
        //   if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        //     res.render("profile",{
        //       profileName: profileName
        //     });
        //   }else{
        //     res.redirect("/");
        //   }
        // })
        
        app.post("/compose", function(req, res) {
        
          const post = new Post({
            title: req.body.postTitle,
            content: req.body.postBody,
            name: profileName
          });
        
          post.save(function(err) {
            if (!err) {
              res.redirect("/blog");
            }
          });
        });
        
        app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res) {
          const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;
        
          Post.findOne({
            _id: requestedPostId
          }, function(err, post) {
            res.render("post", {
              title: post.title,
              content: post.content,
              name: post.name
            });
          });
        
        });
        
        app.get("/about", function(req, res) {
          res.render("about", {
            aboutContent: aboutContent
          });
        });
        
        app.get("/contact", function(req, res) {
          res.render("contact", {
            contactContent: contactContent
          });
        });
        
        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
          console.log("Server started on port 3000");
        });
```

I don't get any errors on my console or just anywhere. It works just fine when I authenticate for the first time but next time I try it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare and edit your code accordingly, OR you can copy this into a new app.js and try to run this but remember to make a backup of your old app.js beforehand and save it somewhere else. And you still need the proper settings in facebook developer to get this running.

```js
//jshint esversion:6
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');
const FacebookStrategy = require("passport-facebook");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(session({
  secret: "This is the secret key",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  facebookId: String,
  secret: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    // console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/secrets"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    // console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("home");
});

app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/secrets',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
      // Successful authentication, redirect home.
      res.redirect('/secrets');
    });


    app.get('/auth/facebook',
      passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['public_profile'] }));

    app.get('/auth/facebook/secrets',
      passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
      function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect('/secrets');
      });



app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
  res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
  res.render("register");
});

app.get("/secrets", function(req, res) {
  // if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
  //   res.render("secrets");
  // } else {
  //   res.redirect("/login");
  // }
  User.find({"secret": {$ne: null}}, function(err, foundUsers) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if (foundUsers) {
        res.render("secrets", {usersWithSecrets: foundUsers});
      }
    }
  });
});

app.get("/submit", function(req, res) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render("submit");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

app.post("/submit", function(req, res) {
  const submittedSecret = req.body.secret;

  console.log(req.user.id);

  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, foundUser) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if (foundUser) {
        foundUser.secret = submittedSecret;
        foundUser.save(function() {
          res.redirect("/secrets");
        });
      }
    }
  });
});

app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
  User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/register");
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
        res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/login", function(req, res) {

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  req.login(user, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
        res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    }
  });

});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page to manage Facebook apps (you, the admin must be logged in): https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Hover over the block containing your live Facebook app and click on the down arrow button that appears on the top right corner. Then select Create Test App from the menu.

Creating a Facebook Test App

The test app will be created with a snapshot of your production app's settings. After this, you can independently edit the settings of your test app without affecting your production app.

See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/

Regarding the rest of the setup:

keep your app in Development mode go to Settings -> Basic (left hand menu) and enter "localhost" for the App Domain change your Site URL to the localhost version (e.g. http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook)

this is for testing the fb login on localhost

Comment: Didn't work got same issue again!!, thanks for the reply btw

Comment: can you show us your code, maybe there are errors in your code

Comment: Its my entire 'app.js'

Comment: I have another problem now, if you can help.... I have created a variable called "profileName" which stores the name of the person who logs into the account.. It works only for kinda one user but suppose me & my friend logs in at a period of time, the one who logged in later, his name is stored in the "profileName" var & his name is displayed for both of the users... Can you give me any idea how to overcome that

Comment: Try using var profileName = "";     or if this doesn't work maybe it has something to do with the schema. If you still encounter problem try to open new thread for the new problem so that other users can focus on that specific problem that you are facing.